# chrome extension - submit values not working

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome extension isn't working, here is my code...

//manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "auto login",
    "description": "With this extension you can auto login.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [ "http://*/*" ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

//   popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submit').click(function(){
                var data = document.getElementById("username").value;
                localStorage["username"] = data;
            });
        });
</script>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form name="login">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Log In</legend>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="verzenden" name="submit" id="submit"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

why isn't this code working?
Can't save the values of username and password by using this script.
Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Never call something in a fom for submit

Comment: So how do I have to solve this?

Comment: Just to add on to the other answers, you can't use any inline code in your popup.html file. Move it all to an external file and include that.

Comment: @BeardFist That's the crucial part of the solution. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never call anything in a form submit
2. return false or call preventDefault to not submit the form
3. Give the form an ID and remove name and ID from the submit button

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#login').on("submit",function(e){
           var data = document.getElementById("username").value;
           localStorage["username"] = data;
           e.preventDefault();
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: I named the <form> id to "login" and removed name and id of <submit> and added your code.. still not retrieving any values..

Answer (score 0):

you must remove the `form` tag from there. when you click the button the form is automatically submitted and your function doesn't have a chance to run